# How do I set the connection string for quartznet-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, connection-string, quartz.net

I am using the following test code and getting an error (shown in the code).  What should my connection string be set to?

I am using Quartz.Impl.MongoDB 1.2, Quartz 2.1.2.400, MongoDB.Bson 1.9.2.235 and MongoDB.Driver 1.9.2.235

I have already tried setting the connection string to "server=mongodb://localhost;database=quartznet;"

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // test that the local mongodb is working
        var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var database = server.GetDatabase("quartznet");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<Entity>("entities");

        var entity = new Entity { Name = "Tom" };
        collection.Insert(entity);
        var id = entity.Id; 

        // local mongodb is working.  Now try to set up a Quartz Scheduler

        var properties = new NameValueCollection();
        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "MyApplicationScheduler"; // needed if you plan to use the same database for many schedulers
        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = System.Environment.MachineName + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks; // requires uniqueness
        properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.MongoDB.JobStore, Quartz.Impl.MongoDB";

        /*
         * From the App.Config
          <connectionStrings>
            <add name="quartznet-mongodb" connectionString="server=localhost;database=quartznet;" />
          </connectionStrings>
         */
        var scheduler = new Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory(properties).GetScheduler(); // error thrown on this line:
        // Inner exception: Invalid connection string 'server=localhost;database=quartznet;'.

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: "mongodb://localhost/quartznet"